# Return zero instead NULL in subquery

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I need to count the posts for each author. I'm using subquery for count them.
But where an author has not post, the result is NULL, but I wish 0.

```
SELECT id, name,
    (SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM posts
    WHERE post.author = authors.id
    GROUP BY author) as post_num
FROM authors
ORDER BY post_num DESC
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coalesce` solve your question, but probably you will get better performance if you use a `LEFT JOIN` so consider try it.

```
 SELECT a.id, a.name, count(post.author) as post_num
 FROM authors a
 LEFT JOIN post p 
        ON a.id = p.author
 GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: This query is called in a backend panel, rarely used. So performance are not so important. The Giorgio's solution is enough for me. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: is ok, Just want share other solution and is also easy to read. Not big fan of inline subquery if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`COALESCE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT id, name,
       COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(id) 
                 FROM posts 
                 WHERE post.author = authors.id 
                 GROUP BY author), 0) as post_num
FROM authors 
ORDER BY post_num DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this by putting the inner select in an IsNull function.

```
Select id, name,
IsNull(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts
       WHERE post.author = authors.id
       GROUP BY author, 0) as post_num
FROM authors
ORDER BY post_num DESC
```

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Basically if the first argument of the IsNull function is NULL, the second argument will be passed. If not, then the result of the firt argument will be passed.

Comment: I'm reading about differences between "COALESCE" and "ISNULL", I didn't understand completely, but in my case I think is the same.